# Validate South Africa Cell Phone Number

Tags: php

How can I validate a South African cell phone number?
The number must start with the country code like +27 and be max 11 digits long - total 12 with the "+" sign.

Comment: Don't forget that future numbers might be longer.

Comment: It is not a reasonable assumption that it will in the near future. 9 years later it is still the same length.

Comment: It might take 20 years but eventually it will be longer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try a regular expression like:

```
^\+27[0-9]{9}$
```

Translated to PHP that would be:

```
if( preg_match( "/^\+27[0-9]{9}$/", $phoneNumber ) ){
  echo "Valid number";
} else {
  echo "Invalid number";
}
```

Comment: Please do NOT use this. Every site that validates phone numbers badly makes me leave straight away. Allow hyphens and spaces, don't force the +.

Comment: @Coronatus: The number must validate under these conditions: 'The number must start with the country code like +27 and be max 11 digits long - total 12 with the "+" sign'. Allowing whitespaces and hyphens will make the number longer than 12 characters.

Comment: @Coronatus - I don't see the problem in forcing your users to type a valid phonenumber - just like a valid username or email. Controlling the users input is a fairly good practice when you wan't to protect your application.

Comment: @Harmenm @Repox - Not everybody (or every culture) writes phone numbers as one long list of numbers. Many people and cultures use hyphens, spaces, or every dots. The non-numeric characters should be removed server-side (see my answer).

Comment: @Coronatus: Read the question one more time, it states: `The number must start with the country code like +27 and be max 11 digits long - total 12 with the "+" sign`. Maybe this isn't even about user input.

Comment: @Harmen - 90% chance it is about user input. It doesn't matter what the question says. If someone writes "how do I parse HTML in regex", they should be told of the downsides and why not to use regex for that. This is a similar case.

Comment: It matters what the question says. The answer is for a specific use case, for the exact details in the question provided. It does not and should not include the front-end for user input format, number grouping, country code selection, even regionalization/internationalization handling, and many other user input nuances.

Answer (score 14):

The OP was for a South African **cell phone** (mobile) number not just any South African telephone number.

The following regex is what worked for me:

```
^(\+27|0)[6-8][0-9]{8}$
```

- Allow for international dialling code or starting with zero.
- South African cell numbers start with 08 or 07 or 06.

Answer (score 1):

Take the input and strip out everything which is not a number.

```
// rm all but Numbers
$input = '0123 abc #';
$output = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $input);
echo($output);
```

Count the remaining digits.

If it is 9 digits long, prepend "+27"

If it is 11 digits long prepend a "+"

If it is 10 digits long or less than 9, then presumably it is not a valid tel number format?

Answer (score 1):

Best use Regex - `0((60[3-9]|64[0-5]|66[0-5])\d{6}|(7[1-4689]|6[1-3]|8[1-4])\d{7})`

Regex tester - https://www.regextester.com/?fam=105448

[source](http://wa.rwick.com/2016/06/09/validating-south-african-cell-numbers-with-a-regular-expression-regex/)

Comment: 0677708709 is a valid mobile number, but its invalid as per above Regex.

Answer (score 0):

```
$number = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $number);
if ((substr($number, 0, 2) != '27') || strlen($number) != 11)
{
    return false;
}
// else valid
```

Comment: If you strip off all non-numbers first, a 'phone number' like `27abc554def23565` is valid too...